# Exception Value:NOT NULL constraint failed: auth_user.username

Tags: django

I am creating a project to register and view profile using Django.

The problem is when I am trying to register a new user I am getting some errors

**NOT NULL constraint failed: auth_user.username**

Here is my form.py and view.py file:

**form.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm,UserChangeForm

class FileDataForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    file = forms.FileField()
    image = forms.ImageField()

class userregister(UserCreationForm):

    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required = False ,help_text ='optional')
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required = False ,help_text ='optional')
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=254, help_text='Required. Inform a valid email address.')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', )


class editprofileform(UserChangeForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email','password')
```

**View.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render 
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect,render_to_response
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.views.generic import View
from .models import FileData
from .forms import FileDataForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import  User
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .forms import userregister,editprofileform
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserChangeForm , PasswordChangeForm
from django.contrib.auth import update_session_auth_hash



# Create your views here.
@login_required
def home(request):
     return HttpResponse('<h1>Welcome to your first page<h1>')


def registration(request):
    print request
    print 'request'
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #save the user data
        form = userregister(request.POST)
        print form.errors
        print 'here'
        if form.is_valid():
            print 'i am here'
            form.save()
            return render(request , 'registration/success.html' ,{'form' : form,} )
        else:
            form =  userregister()
            return render(request , 'registration/register.html' ,{'form' : form,} )
    else:
        form =  userregister()
        return render(request , 'registration/register.html' , {'form': form,})
```

**models.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

# Create your models here.

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user        = models.OneToOneField(User)
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 100,default='')
    city        = models.CharField(max_length =30)
    mobile      = models.IntegerField(default=0)

def create_profile(sender , **kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']:
        user_profile = UserProfile.objects.create(user = kwargs['instance'])

post_save.connect(create_profile , sender=User)
```

**error:**

Exception Value:
NOT NULL constraint failed: auth_user.username

Comment: You'll need to use a custom `User` model if you're looking to use email as the username, because the standard `User` model expects a not-null username. Have a look at: https://www.fomfus.com/articles/how-to-use-email-as-username-for-django-authentication-removing-the-username

Comment: but i think there is no need to use email as the username

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your form.py file, try inserting 'username' as the first element in the 'fields' list. It looks like you're not using that in the form so when you submit, it's leaving the username null.

Comment: No problem! You should mark this as answered for anyone else who sees this in the future.